# error: use of deleted function. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.8

I am trying to create a function that applies an arbitrary functor `F` to every element of a provided tuple:

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

// apply a functor to every element of a tuple
namespace Detail {

template <std::size_t i, typename Tuple, typename F>
typename std::enable_if<i != std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::type
ForEachTupleImpl(Tuple& t, F& f)
{
    f(std::get<i>(t));
    ForEachTupleImpl<i+1>(t, f);
}

template <std::size_t i, typename Tuple, typename F>
typename std::enable_if<i == std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::type
ForEachTupleImpl(Tuple& t, F& f)
{
}

}

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void ForEachTuple(Tuple& t, F& f)
{
    Detail::ForEachTupleImpl<0>(t, f);
}

struct A
{
    A() : a(0) {}
    A(A& a) = delete;
    A(const A& a) = delete;

    int a;
};

int main()
{
    // create a tuple of types and initialise them with zeros
    using T = std::tuple<A, A, A>;
    T t;

    // creator a simple function object that increments the objects member
    struct F
    {
        void operator()(A& a) const { a.a++; }
    } f;

    // if this works I should end up with a tuple of A's with members equal to 1
    ForEachTuple(t, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Live code example: http://ideone.com/b8nLCy

I don't want to create copies of `A` because it might be expensive (obviously in this example it is not) so I deleted the copy constructor. When I run the above program I get:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:134:25: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
>        : _M_head_impl(__h) { }
> ```

I know that the constructor is deleted (that was intentional) but what I don't understand is why it is trying to make copies of my struct. Why is this happening, and how can I achieve this without copying `A`?

Comment: Isn't there a sort of call stack showing what tried to use the tuple copy constructor?

Comment: As this is a boost related question, I'd suggest adding the boost tag.

Comment: @D'Nabre: It really isn't.  It's a question about why `std::tuple` is trying to copy its members in the first place.

Comment: Is this caused by `T t(0,0,0);` or by `ForEachTuple(t,f);` or in the `ForEachTuple` implementation? (comment things out until you find what exact line is leading to the error)

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem might not be really about something involving boost, but part quant's attempted solution (and error messages) are from boost stuff. So someone familiar with boost pointing out why it should/shouldn't be used, or why boost related errors are coming up might be informative.

Comment: I've modified the question to get rid of boost, and added a link to a live example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem you're getting a "deleted constructor" error for:

```
std::function<void(A)> f = [](A& a) { a.a++; };
```

You're trying to set up a `std::function` that passes an `A` by value.  But `A`, having no copy-constructor, can't be passed by value.

Try matching the actual argument type more carefully:

```
std::function<void(A&)> f = [](A& a) { a.a++; };
```

But since you aren't capturing variables, you can simply try

```
void(*f)(A&) = [](A& a) { a.a++; };
```

You've also got a major problem with the base case of your template recursion: even if you get `enable_if` working, which it seems not to be, you'll have an ambiguous call.  I think you need to also *disable* the main case.

Comment: @quant Looks like the error is coming from the `T t(0, 0, 0);` line. *"prog.cpp:41:18:   required from here"* Nevertheless, if you fixed that you would have still run into the problem that Ben points out, so it looks like his answer is correct, but not complete.

Comment: @cdhowie: clang is processing the construction of `t` just fine, having problems with the base case of the template recursion.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see, so perhaps it's just an issue with this particular version of g++. I was going to speculate that an implicitly-converted value isn't properly being treated as an rvalue and was going to suggest `T t(A(0), A(0), A(0));` to test this theory.

Comment: See updated question: I got rid of the constructor problem but now I get the same issue when I try to call ForEach

Comment: @quant Yeah if that fixed it then it does sound like a g++ problem related to implicit conversion constructors.

Comment: @quant If your update caused compilation to get past the line where you construct the tuple and then fail at a later point, yes, it did fix *something* but it didn't fix *everything*.

Comment: @cdhowie true, but not very consoling.

Comment: @quant Progress is progress. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie I suspect the problem is that `std::get` is returning by value. I just don't know of a workaround...

Comment: @quant According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) it does indeed return a reference.

Comment: @quant: It isn't.  Something in `std::function` is going wrong.  When I use a function pointer instead of a functor, I get a lot further.

Comment: I've updated the question using a `struct` functor and trying to fix the `enable_if`, but now I'm getting errors that the function can't be matched. Ideas?

Comment: @quant The second overload needs to be declared first, so the terminating case is visible to the recursive function: http://ideone.com/1lyE62

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating `std::function<void(A)>` a function with a signature taking an `A` by value is instantiated. To synthesize this function definition a copy or a move of `A` is needed. Since `A` is non-copyable but not made movable, such a constructor doesn't exist.

Of course, there is also this funny thing:

```
T t();
```

which declares a function return a `T` by value requiring a copy. When calling `ForEachTuple(t, f)` this function is referenced and instantiated. You may want to replace this declaration by one of

```
T t;
T t{};
```

(in the answer above I had only looked at the first problem I spotted).